# minimum of absolute value

Tags: statistics, optimization, absolute-value

If we consider the following problem 
$$
\mathbb{E}[(Y-y)^2 | X=x]
$$
I can easily show that the minimum with respect to $y$ occurs at 
$$
y=\mathbb{E}[Y |X=x]
$$
How can I find the minimum of 
$$
\mathbb{E}[|Y-y| | X=x]
$$
with respect to $y$?
Since absolute value is not differentiable, I couldn't do the minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to solve $\displaystyle \min_y E|Y-y|$. Assume that $Y$ has a continuous density $f(y)$ (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure). You can write 
\begin{align*}
E|Y - y| = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |z-y| f(z) dz = \int_{-\infty}^y (y-z) f(z) dz + \int_y^\infty (z-y) f(z) dz 
\end{align*}
The two integrals on the right-hand side are differentiable. (Hint: fundamental theorem of calculus.)